# Youtube video isn't showing in Chrome, but shows in Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, video, youtube

Thank you for your help.

On my site I am embedding youtube videos.  Where the video is suppose to be it isn't showing up, in chrome.  It works on a macs and it also works on PCs, but only on firefox.  Where the video is suppose to be you can "click" on the video and it will start playing, but it is not visible. How do I get it to show up.  I thought it might be hiding behind stuff, so I messed with some z-index stuff, but it isn't working.  Is there something else I should be looking at?

This is how the code is:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="myytplayer" data="https://www.youtube.com/v/FJqOb-TS-0o&enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer&version=3&controls=0&showinfo=0&rel=0" width="500" height="348">
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always">
</object>
```

The video is being pulled from my data base, but is being hosted by YouTube.

Here is the code on firefox:

```
<object id="myytplayer" width="500" height="348" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="https://www.youtube.com/v/FJqOb-TS-0o&enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer&version=3&controls=0&showinfo=0&rel=0">
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always">
</object>
```

I have tried updating my flash drives to see if that is a problem.  I have deleted my cookies.  I have even had other people try it out and it just doesn't show up in chrome.  Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Both your snippet of codes works fine in my Chrome 34 Windows 8.1 machine. Not sure where your issue is coming from. Maybe a system/network/proxy settings specific to Chrome on machines where you are trying from (sometimes Youtube URL are banned from company network).

I would point to the Youtube [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#Embedding_a_Player) anyway. Maybe trying another form of embed can help:

> Best practice: IFrame embeds are the recommended method for embedding a YouTube player because the IFrame will select the appropriate player based on the client's capabilities and available YouTube file formats.

If you use the object tag you should have an embed tag falback inside (see the doc).

Comment: Thank you I will figure out how to make that change.